# trouble comparing equality between two objects in java

Tags: java

I've been having numerous problems getting this project to work correctly but I'm currently stuck on getting this class to work properly. Whats its suppose to do is take the current station from the radio class and pass it along to this class. The problem is i'm trying to select between AM and FM and display the current station. I'm not sure if i'm using the equals method correctly as it keeps returning 0.0 which is the default value of currentStation.

```
public class AutoRadioSystem
{

  private Radio selectedRadio;
  private AMRadio radioAM;
  private FMRadio radioFM; 
  private XMRadio radioXM;

  public AutoRadioSystem()
  {
    selectedRadio = new AMRadio();
  }
  public double getCurrentStation()
  {
    if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
    {
      return radioAM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioFM))
    {
      return radioFM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    return 0.0;
  }
  public void selectRadio()
  {
    //if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
     // selectedRadio = radioFM;
  }
  public boolean equals (Object o)    
 {        
   if (o == null)           
     return false;        
   if (! (o instanceof AutoRadioSystem))           
     return false;       
   AutoRadioSystem other = (AutoRadioSystem) o;       
   return this.selectedRadio == other.selectedRadio;    
 }
  public static void main (String [] args) { 
    AutoRadioSystem c = new AutoRadioSystem();
    //c.selectRadio();
    double b = c.getCurrentStation();
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: What?? [Why repost your previous question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991232/trouble-over-riding-and-using-equals-method-in-java/18991350#18991350)

Comment: And just as I answered in your previous question, "You'll want to learn the difference between the tests `ObjA == ObjB`, `ObjA.equals(ObjB)`, and `ObjA instanceof ClassB`."

Comment: If you're going to use `radioAM` and `radioFM`, don't you need to set them to something, somewhere?

Comment: Actually, this is the **third** time you've posted this question.  [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988984/logic-error-possibly-misunderstanding-in-java-assignment), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991232/trouble-over-riding-and-using-equals-method-in-java)

Comment: I used your guys first suggestions and got stuck again. I tried tweaking the question around so that maybe i was more specific where i was getting stuck. I very new to all this.

Comment: I'm really trying to figure out how to initialize radioAM, radioFM, and radioXM correctly so they do not default to null.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've been at this all day long. I finally realize what you meant now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing it wrong (tm).
The `Radio` interface should expose the `getCurrentStaion()` method which will be implemented by all 3 radio classes.  Then your `getCurrentStation()` method can just invoke `selectedRadio.getCurrentStation()` and return its result.

Also you are implementing equals() method in the AutoRadioSystem which will have no effect when comparing Radio instances.

Answer (score 0):

Note that simply with

```
private Radio selectedRadio;
private AMRadio radioAM;
private FMRadio radioFM; 
private XMRadio radioXM;

public AutoRadioSystem()
{
    selectedRadio = new AMRadio();
}
```

`radioAM`, `radioFM`, and `radioXM` are all initialized to `null`, by default.

Any proper `equals()` method will immediately return `false` when comparing with a `null` reference. So in this

```
public double getCurrentStation()
{
    if (selectedRadio.equals(radioAM))
    {
        return radioAM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    else if (selectedRadio.equals(radioFM))
    {
        return radioFM.getCurrentStaion();
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

none of the `if` will evaluate to `true`, and you will get the last case of returning `0.0`.

On top of implementing their `equals()` method correctly, you'll need to initialize them correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Java are a bit differents when it comes to comparing them, as you can compare objects in two ways.

- You can compare the objects's references, by using `==`.
- And you can let a self-made method do a customized check, by using `o1.equals(o2)` where `o1,o2` are objects.

Note that `o instanceof AutoRadioSystem` returns `false` if `o==null` and does not throw a NullPointerException.

PS: There are other issues as well as answered in your previous question.